# Best Practices for naming third party dependencies in maven?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

So I'm upgrading an old project to Maven, and some of the JAR's in the project are missing concrete version numbers, so I'm unable to find them in any existing Maven repositories. Ex: theres a jar just named "hibernate-tools" and "hibernate3", and i'm unable to resolve the exact versions in the hibernate repository. I've got about 20 jars like this.

My company has a repository for third party jars that I can upload these jars to, my question though is how should I label the groupId and the artifactId of these jars to uniquely identify/distinguish them from hibernate jars present in repositories?

Comment: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a convention or best practice for such a rare case. It shouldn't really matters how exactly you name them. I would probably give them a special group id so that there won't be any conflicts with other versions and that makes it clear that those jars should be used together.

By the way, there seem to be [a few ways you could try to get the version](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003161).

- Logging with INFO level should show the main hibernate version at startup
- Jars usually have a `meta-inf/MANITFEST.MF` file which may contains the version
- [`Environment.VERSION` property or `Version.getVersionString()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.html#VERSION)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to find out the exact versions like kapep suggested you can just use publicly available versions.

For others I would suggest give them your own company's groupId (com.mycompany) when adding to your private repo. For version just pick 1.0 (doesn't matter).